# Issues converting angular 1.x controller to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

New to TypeScript and trying to convert from js to ts (using angular 1.x). Here's a controller. Having issues converting to ts. "module" is a custom data element on the ui-router state provider.

```
(function(module) {
    "use strict";
    module.controller("aboutController", [
        "$state",
        function($state) {
            var vm = this;
            // pass the module to the service to get the content for the about page
            // $state.current.data.module
            vm.content = $state.current.data.module;
        }
    ]);
} (angular.module("app.ui")));
```

My latest attempt using ts:

```
module myApp.ui {
    "use strict";
    class AboutController {
        constructor(private $state: ng.ui.IStateProvider) {
            this.content = $state.current.data.module;
        }
    }
    angular.module("app.ui").controller("aboutController", AboutController);
}
```

**Errors**:
error TS2339: Property 'content' does not exist on type 'AboutController'.
error TS2339: Property 'current' does not exist on type 'IStateProvider'.

**Fixes**:
(1) I should have been using IStateService, not IStateProvider - resolves 'current' bug, #2 above.
(2) add the line 'public content: string;' above the ctor - resolves the 'content' bug, #1 above. Thx @Brocco

Comment: And what is it that doesn't work?

Comment: Found my first problem. Was using IStateProvider instead of IStateService.

Comment: For the 'content' error, do I need to explicitly declare a class member? Is this required in TypeScript, unlike js?

Comment: @Ed.S. yes, just add the line `content: any` above your constructor (or below)

Answer (score 2):

> Property 'content' does not exist on type 'AboutController'

You need to declare *all* class properties in TypeScript:

```
class AboutController {
    content: any; // property declaration
    constructor(private $state: ng.ui.IStateProvider) {
        this.content = $state.current.data.module;
    }
}
```

> Property 'current' does not exist on type 'IStateProvide`

Use `IStateService`. Note : these are generally *services* that you inject anyways and the suffix is consistent.